# Merge multi data sources to sink and keep up to date

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-flink

My business has many tables in different MySQL instances, now we want to build a searching platform.

So we have to extract and join them to a width column table, insert them to elastic search, and keep them up to date in es.

In addition, We have an application that converts MySQL binlog to changing message and deliver them to Kafka.

Is there a suitable solution? Can Flink or Materialize help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> have an application that converts MySQL binlog to changing message and deliver them to Kafka

That's a start.

You would then need to do the same with your "width column table", and try to put that into a Kafka KTable, which you can then `join` using Kafka Streams or ksqlDB, as one example. Flink may work as well here.

After you have a joined stream+table written into a new Kafka topic, you can use Kafka Connect Elastic connector, or again, try using Flink, Logstash, etc, to ingest into the search indicies.

One everything is running, any new inserts to either table will be reflected in Elastic.